# React Hooks form OnSubmit makes Problems

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, vite

Hey i cant find a solution why my code dosent work. When i trigger the button nothing happens, normally i want to display the data but nothing happend. My Code is in attachment.
if someone has an idde to solve the problem I would be very grateful.
I have looked at other posts but nothing helps with my Problem.

```js
export default function FormDialog(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
  } = useFormContext();

  let isError = false;
  let errorMessage = "";
  if (errors && errors.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    isError = true;
    errorMessage = errors[name].message;
  }

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    props.func();
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    props.setMenge(event.target.value);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (errors) {
      console.log(errors);
    }
  }, [errors]);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Umbuchen
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Umbuchung</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Bitte geben Sie die Menge ein die umgelagert werden soll!
          </DialogContentText>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name={props.name}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextField
                {...field}
                label={props.label}
                error={isError}
                helperText={errorMessage}
                autoFocus
                margin="dense"
                id="menge"
                type="number"
                fullWidth
                variant="standard"
              />
            )}
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Schließen</Button>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
            Umbuchen
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}
export default function Home() {
  const [sEingang, setSEingang] = useState([]);
  const [sLager, setSLager] = useState("");
  const [menge, setMenge] = useState(0);
  const context = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const { data: warendata } = useWaren(context.access_token);
  const { data: lagerdata } = useGetLager(context.access_token);
  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationShema),
    mode: "all",
  });
  const { getValues, reset, watch, handleSubmit } = methods;
  const waren = watch("selWaren");

  const { data: chargendata, refetch } = useChargen({
    access_token: context.access_token,
    lager: waren,
  });
  const { mutateAsync, isError: mutError, isLoading, isSuccess } = useAnlegen();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getToken() {
      const res = await context.setTokenSilently();
    }
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getToken();
    }, 30000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("data: ", data);
  };



  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <ButtonAppBar name={"Wareneingänge"} back={false} onClick={reset} />


      <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Grid
            container
            spacing={0}
            direction="column"
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="center"
            sx={{p: 2, m: 3}}
            style={{ minHeight: "50vh",  }}
          >
            <Grid item xs={3}>
              <MySelect
                formname={"selWaren"}
                data={warendata}
                name={"Wareneingänge"}
                selected={sEingang}
                setSelected={setSEingang}
                reset={reset} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
              <MySelect
                formname={"selLager"}
                data={lagerdata}
                name={"Freie Lagerplätze"}
                selected={sLager}
                setSelected={setSLager} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
              <MySelect
                formname={"selChargen"}
                data={chargendata}
                name={"Freie Chargenplätze"}
                selected={sLager}
                setSelected={setSLager} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ m: 3}}>
              <FormDialog
                func={onSubmit}
                name={"selMenge"} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've forgotten to add an `onClick` handler for the submit button here:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
  Umbuchen
</Button>
```

Something like this should work:

```
<Button onClick={() => props.func()} variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
  Umbuchen
</Button>
```

Comment: No sorry this is not the solution. type="submit" add it to the form